# Call window.open() inside loop during handling of element click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to call window.open() inside loop x times (target=_blank) based on some criteria. But it opens new tab just one time. Is anything I'm doing wrong? Here is my code

```
$('#spogo_' + _sp.spid).button()
     .button('option', 
        {
             label : 'Go to',
             icons : {
                 primary : 'ui_icon_goto'
             }
        })
    .on('click', function(){
         var selRow = model._getSelectedRow($('#spt_' + this.id.split('spogo_')[1]).dataTable())[0];
         for(var i = 0 ; i < selRow.cells.length ; i ++){
             var cell = selRow.cells[i];
             if($(cell).hasClass('vdata_cell')){
                  window.open($(cell).attr('data'), '_blank');
             }
         }
    });
```

I've tried debug this and found that `if` happens multiple times, by the way during debug neither URL was opened.

**EDIT:** Aaahh sorry guys the popup was blocked :D
But now one url opens inside new tab, another in new window, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why in the world are you looping and checking a class? Just use a selector to find the element.

Comment: What is the value of $(cell).attr('data')?  I just tried `window.open('http://www.cheese.com', '_blank')` and it opens multiple tabs.

Comment: http://www.google.com :)

Comment: @Mark maybe the reason is that I'm calling inside click() event handler?

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan Shouldn't make any difference, is your url fully formatted?

Comment: @Mark sorry popup was blocked :D I've edited the post new problem is available

Comment: I coded something very similar and faced the issue where content gets mixed up in the new tabs. I resolved it by giving a time-buffer in between opening tabs in loop. 500ms was enough to prevent the mix-up from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify the `'_blank'` and then the users browser is going to decide if it is in a new tab or a new window and you can not override that "feature".

Comment: :( Thanks. But clicking with 'Ctrl' pressed it opened in new tabs

Comment: By default, most browsers open `ctrl+click` links in a new tab.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti can we override this feature? To handle every click like ctrl+click?

Comment: No we can't, and I don't think we should be able to.  This is up to the user.  I believe `window.open` may open in a window instead of a tab (despite the user's setting) if there is a size defined (browser dependent), but a link with `target="_blank"` will follow the browser preference setting.

Comment: When I use ctrl+click in Chrome it still opens tabs in new separate windows. I guess it is entirely upon the browser how this will work out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resolve this, it is a user preference in their browser for where they wish the link to be opened. It is also frowned upon from a usability standpoint to force users to open links in a new window

Answer (score 0):

Check the spec for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).  The way you have it written `window.open(url, '_blank')` is creating one window named `_blank` and opening the url in that same window each time.  Try changing the name by appending a number from a counter or something.

As far as opening in a tab vs. a window - that is a preference in the browser, and you have no control over it.

Comment: Is that what you were trying to do?